# Accessing a method with specifying that a class does not have parameters

Tags: swift

In a tutorial when I tried to refer to a class without specifying that it has no parameters, it did not allow me to reach a method on it.

`NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(display.text!)!.doubleValue`

When I did not put `()` after `NSNumberFormatter`, it did not allow me to have `doubleValue`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`numberFromString` is an instance method, so you need to call it with an instance of the class.

`NSNumberFormatter()` creates an instance of the class; it is shorthand for `NSNumberFormatter.init()`.  That is why:

```
NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(display.text!)!.doubleValue
```

works.

---

When you call `NSNumberFormatter.numberFromString`, that returns a function that requires an instance of the class `NSNumberFormatter` to be turned into a function that you can then call with a `String`.

In a Playground, if you do:

```
let f = NSNumberFormatter.numberFromString
```

and then <kbd>Option</kbd>-click on `f`, you find that its type is:

```
let f: NSNumberFormatter -> (String) -> NSNumber?
```

Note that you could call the function like this:

```
NSNumberFormatter.numberFromString(NSNumberFormatter())(display.text!)!.doubleValue
```

because that supplies the needed instance of `NSNumberFormatter` to `NSNumberFormatter.numberFromString` to access the instance method.

Comment: Thanks man, so If I'm right, it means that putting a `()` means it calls a class, otherwise it calls a function. Am I right ?

Comment: Putting `()` calls the initializer for the class to create an instance.  `NSNumberFormatter()` is shorthand for `NSNumberFormatter.init()`.

Comment: Ow, now I get it ! Thanks for the help :)